# getting undefined variable when passing data from controller to view in laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel

I'm trying to send data from controller to view using AJAX but getting ‘undefined variable’. Fixed my problem so updating my functions.

Here is my AJAX function:

```
<script>
  jQuery(document).ready(function(emp_get_id){
  jQuery('#edit_button').live('click', function(event) 
  {     
    jQuery('#edit-user').toggle('show');
    var emp_id = $(this).parent().find('input[type="hidden"][name="emp_get_id"]').val();
    var token = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');

    $.ajax({
        url: 'get-user-details',
        type: "post",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {emp_id, _token:token},
        success: function(data)
        {
            $.each(data,function(i,item)
            { 
              $("#emp_id").val(item.id);
              $("#edit_name").val(item.name);
              $("#email_id").val(item.email);

            })
        }
    });
  });
  });
</script>
```

and my route:

```
Route::get('get-user-details', 'ABC\ABCController@GetUserDetails')
    ->name('get-user-details');
```

controller:

```
public function GetUserDetails(Request $request)
{
    $res_data = $request->all();
    $emp_data = DB::table('employee_master')
                ->select('*')
                ->join('role_master', 'employee_master.role_id', '=', 'role_master.role_id')
                ->where('Emp_id',$res_data['emp_id'])
                ->get();
    return response($emp_data);
}
```

Comment: Why/how are you using `jQuery` and `$`? Where do you get this error, what line/col number does it say it’s on, and what does that refer to?

Answer (score 0):

On this line:

```
var emp_id = $(this).parent().find('input[type="hidden"][name="emp_get_id"]').val();
```

do you mean `[name="' + emp_get_id + '"]` instead?

Comment: yes, I'm getting error in my view section, when trying to print emp_data.

Comment: You need to post your view. Do you have an input named `emp_get_id`?

Comment: I'm taking my id with emp_get_id through input type hidden.

Comment: You need to post your code, we can’t help if we can’t see the code.

Comment: <?php echo $emp_data['Emp_name'][0];?> this is i'm using in view

Comment: {Emp_id: 30, Emp_name: "ABC", Emp_Address: null, gender: null, phone_no: null, …} this is the result i'm getting in console, my problem is I don't know how to send this data to php.

Comment: Why do you need to send it ‘to’ PHP – what are you trying to make happen?

Comment: Hi, I was making a mistake, updating my answer.